# Embedding Office files into SharePoint pages

Tags: office-integration, word

Is it possible to embed Office documents into SharePoint publishing pages? This way the user doesn't have to open the file; its contents display inline on the page or in an iframe. The files will be stored in a local SharePoint 2010 library (not on the Internet). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use Word Automation services and create an HTML version of each document. These HTML files could then be deployed to your appropriate environment.

Answer (score 5):

Use an iframe with the URL to the Office Web Apps page. For instance use the Page Viewer Web Part.

Comment: Thanks, Wictor. We can't publish the documents outside of the organization; they must remain on the intranet (even though they'd be in a private cloud with Office Web Apps). Any solution in this scenario?

Comment: Added another answer with a different approach.